# Ubuntu installer over PXE doesn't see network adapters => can't download preseed

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, boot, pxe-boot, preseed

I'm booting one virtualbox VM from another virtualbox VM (with cobbler) over PXE. Both machines have 2 adapters: 1) external network and 2) host-only network.

The "client" VM successfully boots into the installer over PXE (using the host-only network adapter), but then the installer doesn't even try to download the preseed file (according to server logs) or get an IP address (again according to server logs - which *do* show the TFTP requests before).

I drop into a shell and see that:

- "ip a" shows only the loopback adapter
- Reading dmesg shows that apparently no adapters have been found
- lsmod seems to show no signs of network adapter modules either
- lspci *does* show both network controllers.
- There are essentially no drivers in /lib/modules/...../kernel/drivers/net (**probably this is the reason?**)

How do I make the installer see my network adapters, or at least how do I find the cause of this problem?

Here's the PXE menu entry:

```
default linux
prompt 0
timeout 1
label linux
        kernel /images/ubuntu-10.04-server-x86_64/vmlinuz
        ipappend 2
        append initrd=/images/ubuntu-10.04-server-x86_64/initrd.gz  locale=  interface=auto text root=/dev/sda1 priority=critical  auto url=http://192.168.56.101/cblr/svc/op/ks/system/pierrot hostname=pierrot domain=local.lan suite=lucid
```

Answer (score 5):

OK, I figured it out.

Turns out that there are two initrd images in the Ubuntu ISO that I was using:

```
[jkff@localhost tmp]$ find /mnt/ubuntu-server/ -name 'initrd.gz'
/mnt/ubuntu-server/install/initrd.gz
/mnt/ubuntu-server/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz
```

The first one of these does not include network drivers. The second one does. Cobbler picked the first one (due to [this](https://github.com/cobbler/cobbler/blob/57a36d86bfbe13b8284028e6d87bba386ee3d037/cobbler/modules/manage_import_debian_ubuntu.py#L267)), so of course without network drivers it couldn't find the NICs and download the preseed.

Now I have to figure out a way to make Cobbler use the proper initrd...

Answer (score 0):

I got cobbler to use the correct initrd by editing the distro to point to the correct initrd, which in my case lived at /var/www/cobbler/ks_mirror/ubuntu-12.04.1-server-amd64-x86_64/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz