# Searching for ubuntu installation media fails pxeboot

Tags: pxe-boot, tftp

I'm setting up a pxe setup for my cluster.
I'm using dnsmasq as the dhcp/tftp server, and try to deploy ubuntu server 14.04.2.
I'm using apache2 as http server to serve the preseed and such.

dnsmasq:

```
dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0
enable-tftp
tftp-root:/tftp/pxeboot
```

my tree looks like

```
/tftpboot
--/tftpboot/pxeboot
----/tftpboot/pxeboot/pxelinux.0
----/tftpboot/pxeboot/pxelinux.cfg/default
----/tftpboot/pxeboot/pxelinux.cfg/vesamenu.c32
----/tftpboot/pxeboot/boot/14.04.2
```

Where the content of `/tftpboot/pxeboot/boot/14.04.2` is the exact result of

```
mount -o loop ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso /mnt
cp -R /mnt /tftp/pxeboot/boot/14.04.2
```

My client is able to retrieve the `pxelinux.cfg/default` file, which is made of the following lines:

```
default boot/14.04.2/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/vesamenu.c32
menu title ubuntu server install
Label u14.02.2_server
    menu label ubuntu-server-14.04.2-amd64
    kernel boot/14.04.2/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
    append vga=788 initrd=boot/14.04.2/install/initrd.gz ksdevice=eth0 locale=en_US.UTF-8 keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us interface=eth0 hostname=unassigned url=http://X.X.X.X/14.04.2/preseed/preseed.txt live-installer/net-image=http://X.X.X.X/14.04.2/install/filesystem.squashfs -- quiet
```

The client retrieve the initrd (fact that I can see in the dnsmaq's machine system log), then start the installation. I'm not prompted anything, but the installation stalls at `Detect and mount CD-ROM`

The log file on the client shows the following:

```
[...]cdrom-detect: Searching for Ubuntu installation media
[...]cdrom-detect: Devices: ''
[...]cdrom-detect: Devices: ''
[...]cdrom-detect: Devices: ''
[...]cdrom-detect: Devices: ''
[...]cdrom-detect: Devices: ''
[...]cdrom-detect: Devices: ''
[...]cdrom-detect: Devices: ''
[...]cdrom-detect: Devices: ''
[...]cdrom-detect: Devices: ''
```

**Is there any other option I must give for the client to find the installation files on the server side? Did I misunderstood how the http client/Server dialogue server those file after the initrd was loaded?**

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the initrd I used was not containing the proper drivers

I followed the self-answered solution here:

[Ubuntu installer over PXE doesn't see network adapters => can't download preseed](https://serverfault.com/questions/403222/ubuntu-installer-over-pxe-doesnt-see-network-adapters-cant-download-preseed)